# Find the stray number

Tags: javascript

Practicing some katas in Code Wars and ran into this "Find the stray number" - I thought this was a pretty simple exercise (thank God I am started to feel comfortable with these challenges), but I am failing one of the test. Not sure why I am failing the test, nor does the site give me any ideas of what the array is they are passing

Below is the code that I used - if anyone can help me out that would be great.

Here is the link to the challenge & question

---

https://www.codewars.com/kata/find-the-stray-number/train/javascript

> You are given an odd-length array of integers, in which all of them are the same, except for one single number.
>
> Complete the method which accepts such an array, and returns that single different number.
>
> The input array will always be valid! (odd-length >= 3)
>
> Examples
> [1, 1, 2] ==> 2
> [17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17] ==> 3

```
function stray(numbers) {
let strayChar = numbers[0];

 for(let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
  if(strayChar !== numbers[i]){
  return strayChar = numbers[i];
   }
 }
       return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the task question to your post as well?

Comment: just edited with the task as well as link to codewars challenge

Comment: It will fail when the first element in the array (`numbers[0]`) is the stray number, e.g. `stray([2,1,1,1])` returns `1` when it should return `2`.

Comment: 1. compare the first two elements. 2. if they are the same, compare every subsequent element against the first one, first mismatch is stray 3. if they aren't the same, compare first and third => equal => 2nd element is stray, not equal => 1st is stray

Comment: `numbers.reduce(function(a,b) { return a^b; })`

Answer (score 1):

Here, we do a `find` to find an element, using the evaluator `filter` and test is simple. Find an element that has a filtered array length of 1.

```js
let testArrays = [[1, 1, 2], [17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17]];

function stray(numbers) {
  return numbers.find((e) => numbers.filter((v) => v===e).length === 1); 
} 

testArrays.forEach(arr => {
  console.log(stray(arr));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this by using Set, Map, Array#from, Array#slice, and Array#find.

Use `Set` to find the unique numbers in the list. Then simply only loop through the first 3 elements of the list. If one of the unique numbers has a count greater than 1, that means the other unique number must be the odd one.

```js
const data = [17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17];

function stray(numbers){
  //find unique numbers and set their count to 0
  const map = new Map(Array.from(new Set(numbers)).map(v=>([v,0])));
  
  //take first three numbers from numbers array
  return Array.from(
      numbers.slice(0,3).reduce((a,c)=>{
        //update the count
        return map.set(c, map.get(c) + 1);
      }, map)
      //find the number with a count of 0 or 1
  ).find(([,v])=>v<=1)[0];
}

const res = stray(data);

console.log(res);
```

One of the more impressive solutions offered on code wars is:

```js
const data = [17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17];
const stray = nums => nums.reduce((a, b) => a ^ b);


const res = stray(data);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: The XOR solution appears to rely on there being an odd number of entries in the source array. Adding another `17` makes the output come out as `18`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int stray(numbers) {
  numbers.sort();
  int ans = (numbers[0] == numbers[1]) ? numbers.last : numbers.first;

  return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stray(numbers) {
    //take first element
    let strayChar = numbers[0];

    // see if it is different from the next 2
    if (strayChar !== numbers[1] && strayChar !== numbers[2]) return strayChar;

    // if not find the first value that is different
    for(let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
      if(strayChar !== numbers[i])return numbers[i];
    }
 }
 
 const data = [17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17];
 console.log(stray(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const stray = numbers => {
  let number = 0

  numbers.forEach(x => numbers.indexOf(x) ? number = x : null)
  return number
}
console.log(stray([17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17]))
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stray(numbers) {
    const result =  numbers.find(number => numbers.indexOf(number) === numbers.lastIndexOf(number));
    console.log(result)
}
stray([1, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score -2):

i know it's been more than year but the error you had was just because the extra '=' in the if statement

Comment: The issue isn't of comparison between different data types, consider this case `[2,1,2]` OPs answer would fail for such cases.